# Find difference from IList<string[]> one and IList<string[]> two using Linq operation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi is there any build in method using Linq or lambda expression or any other approach we can get records which is present and in `IList<string[]>` one but not in `IList<string[]>` two or vise versa. I tried with linq Except keyword but its not working, it's working perfect when I am doing operation on string[] not on `IList<string[]>`.

Comment: The [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) method is described to produce *"the members of the first set that do not appear in the second set"* which appears to be what you want. Could you please provide a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem? What is the actual output and what is the expected output?

Comment: IList<string[]> one = parseCSV(Path) and IList<string[]> two = parseCSV(Path1) and IList<string[]> except=one.Except(two).ToList(); but it always returing IList<string[]> one which is not correct. there is one record match in both Ilist and it should be removed in result output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151(v=vs.100).aspx) for `string[]`, arrays are compared by reference by default. Even if the elements of your arrays are same, the *references* are different.So the `Except` method treats them as different.

```
class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        // do your comparison here
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string[] obj)
    {
        // write your hash algorithm 
    }

}
```

Then you can use this comparer by passing [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390(v=vs.100).aspx) method like this:

```
var result = list1.Except(list2, new ArrayComparer());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for response I am facing issue only when I have List<string[]>. Code is working fine when I am working on class but passing string array in same code I am not getting as expected (code is not calling Equal method in case of string[])

Comment: After return 1 statement in all case from GetHashCode(string[] obj) method it worked for my case earlier I was returning obj.GetHashCode(). thanks for the help